# WordPress sub pages not displaying anymore

Tags: wordpress, apache, caching

I created a website for our upcoming wedding and I wanted to add cache to the site. Installed WP Super Cache and now only the homepage works.

All other pages go to a directory index:

```
Index of /hotel-travel
[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
[PARENTDIR] Parent Directory        -    
[   ]   meta-wp-cache-dde84fef2e36c68d9ea71ec5fc6a8be0.php  2020-03-13 
12:47   502  
Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at www.example.com Port 443
```

Please help. people are trying to look at this

Answer (score 0):

Don't panic and first turn off the cache plugin (you could remove the plugin folder from wp-content/plugins using FTP or whatever way you manage website files). This will ensure your website works again and people can see it.

Then, consider trying W3Cache plugin wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/ for page caching, it is proven to work well.

Comment: OK, problem was that it created folders in the root domain. Deleting those fixed the problem.